# WooCommerce dokan: get all category from store id or seller id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I just work in a large e-commerce unit and my client wants to display a category-wise seller count and a list of category-wise sellers in Woocommerce. For each I get an answer for a specific seller but for a large amount of sellers it became complex code.

How to get all categories from store id or seller id or any other solution?

Comment: Please add editing your question the both answers code that you are using for getting categorywise seller count  and a list of categorywise sellers. Thanks